# Doctrine ORM Custom Column Collation

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to set custom column collation as in Doctrine documentation:

- http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/schema-representation.html and
- http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html

using

`@ORM\Column(name="body", type="string", length=140, options={"customSchemaOptions"={"collate"="utf8mb4_unicode_ci"}})`

but when I update the schema it always goes back to utf8_unicode_ci (when I set it manually for example). Any ideas?

Comment: which database do you use? cause the collate option is only supported on SQL Server

Comment: Oh, I'm using MySQL. There's no ORM options to set the column collation for a MySQL DB?

Comment: http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/schema-representation.html at chapter 10.1.1.3:
"collate (string): The collation to use for the column. Currently only supported on SQL Server."

So collate for MySQL isn't supported according the docs

Comment: See answer below as it's been added by now.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This has been added by now if you (or someone else) still need, see [column annotation docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_column)

Example: In annotations:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=false, options={"collation":"utf8_bin"})
 */
private $code;
```

In Yaml:

```
Your\Nice\Entity:
    fields:
        code:
            type: string
            length: 64
            options:
                collation: utf8_bin   # Although the recommendation is the utf8mb4* set now.
```

This is supported by all common database drivers now.

Comment: It is supported indeed but not portable. if you set the collation to "utf8_bin", it will fail on sqlite.