# How do I make Doctrine respect the column collation defined in YAML?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a YAML document with a ORM schema for an entity, with the following definition:

```
fields:
    message:
        type: text
        nullable: true
        options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

This does not change the column, so I have to update it *by hand* in the database to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. But when I run Symfony's command `doctrine:schema:update` it suggests that I change the column back with

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE message message LONGTEXT  DEFAULT NULL ;
```

which drops the altered collation.

How do I make doctrine either ignore the column in the command, or respect the `options` definition?

Comment: It worked fine for me using annotations. I'd suggest testing whether it works for you using annotations, might give you some insights. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30897421/2106834

Comment: @Jonny The thing is, I'm using YAML. So it seems that it is only available when using annotations, and I don't think I can have both.

Comment: I came across this post. They use collate instead of collation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30795101/2106834