# Case sensitive database values

Tags: mysql, sqlite, doctrine, dbal

I want to store a base64 token in a database. Specifically: I want to store it in a doctrine orm model.

Base64 contains lowercase and upper case letters but mysql and sqlite are case insensitive by default.

I know that you can change the collation of a field as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30897421. But that isn't database agnostic or at least sqlite doesn't like it:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such collation sequence: ascii_bin
```

The only real platform agnostic way I know of is to use a binary type but I don't like that solution because it isn't binary i'm storing.

Is there any elegant way to solve this?

EDIT: I need to clearify. I can store data case sensitive but I can't search for it case sensitive. If I have a unique column then I cant store "hi" and "HI" at the same time. And if the field isn't unique then I always get both. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7c9a7450a4141b296b09b550afba01e

Comment: I think MySQL is not case insensitive by default. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9d8c65081ff02e0bebfdaddedc593f4

Comment: It seems SQLite isn't case insensitive by default either. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ce48d89d71592df616cc42aaa1c1cb15

Comment: @TheImpaler I added a clearification. Of course you can store upper and lower case values but you can't search for them.